# Rails__Association Relationships

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, model-associations, belongs-to, has-one

I have 2 models:

User model and Profile Model.

My association is as follows:

```
Class User < ActiveRecord::Base
 has_one :profile

end


Class Profile < ActiveRecord::Base
belongs_to :user
validates user_id, presence: true
end
```

My Controllers is as follows:

USER:

```
class UsersController < ApplicationController

def show
@user = User.find(params[:id])

if logged_in?
  @micropost    = current_user.microposts.build
  @profile      = current_user.build_profile
  @new_comment  = Comment.build_from(@user, current_user.id, ' ')
end
@microposts     = @user.microposts.paginate(page: params[:page])
@profile_player = @user.profile
end
end
```

PROFILE:

```
class ProfilesController < ApplicationController


before_action :logged_in_user,  only: [:create, :destroy]
  before_action :correct_user,    only: [:destroy]

  def create
    @profile  = current_user.build_profile(profile_params)
    if @profile.save
      flash[:success] = 'Profile Has Been Published'
      # redirect_to request.referrer  ||  root_url
      redirect_to users_url
    else
      render  :'pages/home'
    end
  end

  def update
    @profile.update(profile_params)
    redirect_to user_url
  end


  def destroy
  end

  private
  def profile_params
    params.require(:profile).permit(:name, :age, :nationality, :country, :city, :height, :weight,
                                    :dominant_hand, :play_position, :highschool, :college, :team,
                                    :awards, :highlights)
  end

  def correct_user
    @profile  = current_user.profile.find_by(id:  params[:id])
    redirect_to root_url if @profile.nil?
  end

end
```

Now, what I'm trying to do is render the profile view partial in the user show page (following Michael Hartl's tutorial):

hence I'm rendering the view via the instance variable I created in Users Controller show action for profile:

```
def show
#@username = params[:id] ==============> this is intended to show the user name instead
# of the user id in the address bar
@user = User.find(params[:id])

if logged_in?
  @micropost    = current_user.microposts.build
  @profile      = current_user.build_profile
  @new_comment  = Comment.build_from(@user, current_user.id, ' ')
end
@microposts     = @user.microposts.paginate(page: params[:page])
@profile_player = @user.profile

end
```

so, in my user show page:

I'm rendering the profile view like this:

Now here is the error I run into, my profile saves correctly when the form is submitted, however, when I return to the User show page (I'm rendering the profile form in the user home page) to view the profile, I get the error:

`'nil' is not an ActiveModel-compatible object. It must implement :to_partial_path.`

```
  <div class="current-user-persona">
    <%= render @profile_player %>  =====> highlighted section for error
  </div>
```

I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong here, can you help me?

been staring at this for days.

Comment: I'm not sure, but think that in your params you haven't `:id`, maybe you have `:user_id`.. Take a look to debugging info, you'll see which params do you have.

Comment: params is :user_id

Comment: profile_player instance_variable is mostly likely nil, anyways, even if it's not, since you are rendering the partial directly, it will look in app/views/profiles/_profile.html.erb if the class for @user.profile is 'Profile'

Comment: @JeremyDeey so in your show action you should do `@user = User.find(params[:user_id])` instead of `@user = User.find(params[:id])`

Comment: @nobilik that didn't work

Comment: @ilan berci, how do i fix this then?

Comment: @ilan berci i inspected the object (@profile_player), and yes, its nil. so my question is, how do i get around that?

Comment: If that is the case, establish why "@profile_player = @user.profile" in your controller is not working.  What does @user.profile return?

Comment: how do i do this?

Comment: @JeremyDeey could you update the partial which you are rendering.